# C++ Regex doesn't match string

Tags: c++, regex

I'm facing a problem by using `c++ regex library` i have written a simple program in `java` which check how many times given string is match to the pattern. It give right answer which is `3`.
Code:

```
public class PatternMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count=0;

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab");



        Matcher target = p.matcher("ababbaba");


        while(target.find()){

            count++;

        }

        System.out.println("Number of times : "+count);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Number of times : 3
```

But now i try to implement same program by using regex library in c++ but its not working same that i expected. I give a target string like `ababbaba` and it doesn't count like java and doesn't give output `3`. I want to fix this problem but how could i do that.
Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<regex>


    using namespace std;


    int main() {


        bool check;
        int count = 0;
        regex Pattern("ab");
        string target ="ababbaba";
        smatch match;


        check = regex_match(target, match, Pattern);

            if(check){
                count++;
        }

        cout << count << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You are just using it wrong.

Comment: You can do this better like this: `const auto count = distance(sregex_iterator(cbegin(target), cend(target), Pattern), sregex_iterator());` see this example: http://ideone.com/Lqxbpr

Comment: @JonathanMee can you tell me does distance function is from <iterator> library or not and why you use sregex_iterator() as a last parameter in distance function

Comment: @HarveyClue Teh default constructed [`sregex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator/regex_iterator) is the "end-of-sequence iterator". So I'm measuring the distance from the start of the sequence: `sregex_iterator(cbegin(target), cend(target), Pattern)` to the "end-of-sequence iterator"